# Can't compile static ZFS binaries on Gentoo

Tags: linux, gentoo, compile, zfs

My kernel: geek-sources-3.11.1 from init6 overlay with zfs and couple other patches.

Right now I'm using SysRescCD and doing everything in a chroot.

My last try was:

```
$ grep static-libs /etc/portage/package.use
sys-fs/zfs kernel-builtin static-libs custom-cflags static
=sys-apps/util-linux-2.22.2 static-libs
=sys-libs/zlib-1.2.7 static-libs

$ mkdir /tmp/zfs /tmp/zfsroot
$ cd /tmp/zfs
$ wget http://archive.zfsonlinux.org/downloads/zfsonlinux/zfs/zfs-0.6.2.tar.gz -O-|tar xz

--2013-09-26 10:13:55--  http://archive.zfsonlinux.org/downloads/zfsonlinux/zfs/zfs-0.6.2.tar.gz
Resolving archive.zfsonlinux.org... 176.32.99.47
Connecting to archive.zfsonlinux.org|176.32.99.47|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 2158948 (2.1M) [application/x-gzip]
Saving to: ‘STDOUT’

100%[=========================================================================================================================================================================>] 2,158,948    719KB/s   in 2.9s   

$ cd zfs-0.6.2
$ export CFLAGS='-static -O2 -pipe -march=native' LDFLAGS='-static'
$ ./autogen.sh 2>&1 | wgetpaste
Your paste can be seen here: http://bpaste.net/show/135509/
$ ./configure --disable-shared --enable-static --enable-linux-builtin 2>&1 | wgetpaste
Your paste can be seen here: http://bpaste.net/show/135512/
$ make -j5 2>&1 | wgetpaste
Your paste can be seen here: http://bpaste.net/show/135513/
$ make DESTDIR=/tmp/zfsroot install 2>&1 | wgetpaste
Your paste can be seen here: http://bpaste.net/show/135514/
$ file /tmp/zfsroot/usr/local/sbin/zpool
/tmp/zfsroot/usr/local/sbin/zpool: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.9, not stripped
```